# Map matrix element to string

Tags: string, matlab, dictionary, mapping

I would like to map numeric output from a matrix to a string.

Given

```
compute=[ 7, 4, 3; 3, 4, 7]
```

how can one obtain a string mapping as

```
Out=[Run, Walk, Jog; Jog, Walk, Run]
```

The actual output might be a cell array of strings.

Comment: I love it when one question gets 3 answers in the first five minutes.  You can almost hear the simultaneous shouts of "Ooh! I know this one!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the map in a form of a cell array

```
>> map{3} = 'Jog';
>> map{4} = 'Walk';
>> map{7} = 'Run';
```

Now use the map

```
map( compute )
```

will give you a cell array of strings

Answer (score 3):

```
>> map={'a','b','Jog','Walk','e','f','Run'}

map = 

    'a'    'b'    'Jog'    'Walk'    'e'    'f'    'Run'

>> map(compute)

ans = 

    'Run'    'Walk'    'Jog'
    'Jog'    'Walk'    'Run'
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has a [`Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) [container type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) that makes this very straighftorward:

```
keySet = [7, 4, 3];
valSet = {'Run', 'Walk', 'Jog'};
map = containers.Map(keySet,valSet);
```

Get the requested values:

```
>> vals = values(map,num2cell(compute))
vals = 
    'Run'    'Walk'    'Jog'
    'Jog'    'Walk'    'Run'
```

This is a class after all, so you can also use a more familiar OOP syntax for calling the [`values` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.values.html):

```
>> vals = map.values(num2cell(compute))
vals = 
    'Run'    'Walk'    'Jog'
    'Jog'    'Walk'    'Run'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cell array

strs = {'one','two','Jog','Walk','five','six','Run'};

compute=[ 7, 4, 3; 3, 4, 7];

out = strs(compute);

out =

```
'Run'    'Walk'    'Jog'
'Jog'    'Walk'    'Run'
```